# Javascript / Howler.js - Error loading audio in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, parceljs, howler.js

Firefox 76.0.1
Windows 10 pro
Using Howler.js with Parcel.js and Node in visual Studio Code.

I tried to load this file in 3 different formats: mp3, ogg and webm, but I get in all cases the same error:
The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.
Error null Decoding audio data failed.

Here is some of the code and structure:
[image]

Similar error in Chrome:
Error null Decoding audio data failed.

Comment: I just ran into a similar problem trying to use Howler with Parcel. Using with live server the sounds play, with Parcel, I don't get any errors, but the sounds don't play. 

Were you able to figure out how to use Parcel and Howler together?

Answer (score -1):

I have blamed/queried both lichess.org and mozilla about this and it turns out it's howler.js having issues. Sound won't work in 2/4 of their examples or so in mozilla when a site uses it to deliver sound (lichess.org for example). I don't know who to approach  but I suppose I will have to do it myself.